# Undefined variable when it is under isset

Tags: php, arrays, sum, isset

Create a sum of multiple array, but it shows undefined variable

```
Total Box Charges: <?php if(isset($box_chrs)){echo $a = array_sum($box_chrs);}?><br>
Total Installation Charges: <?php if(isset($instl_chrs)){echo $b = array_sum($instl_chrs);}?><br>
Total Other Charges: <?php if(isset($other_chrs)){echo $c = array_sum($other_chrs);}?><br>
Total Package Charges:<?php if(isset($pkg_val)){echo $d = array_sum($pkg_val);}?><br>
Total Amount: <?php if(isset($total_amt)){echo $e = array_sum($total_amt);}?>
          <br>
Grand Total:
          <?php
          if(isset($a) || isset($b) || isset($c) || isset($d) || isset($e))
          {
            $sum = array($a, $b, $c, $d, $e);
            echo array_sum($sum);
          }
          ?>
```

I use `isset` but in the output it shows `Notice: Undefined variable: a`.
It make sum of other, but when some variable is null, then it shows Undefined variable
.when I set all the variable it shows perfect. If any variable is null, then it shows error.

So my question is
How to sum of those variable?

It is a experimental script I am coding, and I am not in pro yet. :)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: in which line do you get the error?

Comment: @Luceos When $a and $b is null.

Comment: On first line, it seems that you check `$box_chrs` but `$a` undefined!

Comment: @MeNa he is doing right he is assigning $box_chrs to $a so it is $box_chars which need to get checked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Update*

Your code is a bit complicated, I don't think it needs to be. When you want to get the total sum, add the parts where you know they exists - in the individual ifs.

```
<?php $sum = array(); ?>
Total Box Charges: <?php if(isset($box_chrs)){
    echo $a = array_sum($box_chrs);
    $sum[] = $a;
}?><br>
Total Installation Charges: <?php if(isset($instl_chrs)){
    echo $b = array_sum($instl_chrs);
    $sum[] = $b;
}?><br>
Total Other Charges: <?php if(isset($other_chrs)){
    echo $c = array_sum($other_chrs);
    $sum[] = $c;
}?><br>
Total Package Charges:<?php if(isset($pkg_val)){
    echo $d = array_sum($pkg_val);
    $sum[] = $d;
}?><br>
Total Amount: <?php if(isset($total_amt)){
    echo $e = array_sum($total_amt);
    $sum[] = $e;
}?>
          <br>
Grand Total:
<?php
echo array_sum($sum);
?>
```

This will add each part to the `$sum` if it is set. You cannot use one statement for all of these because you don't know which is set. You could do it like this as well, but I'd prefer the solution posted above ;)

```
Total Box Charges: <?php if(isset($box_chrs)){ echo $a = array_sum($box_chrs); }?><br>
Total Installation Charges: <?php if(isset($instl_chrs)){echo $b = array_sum($instl_chrs);}?><br>
Total Other Charges: <?php if(isset($other_chrs)){echo $c = array_sum($other_chrs);}?><br>
Total Package Charges:<?php if(isset($pkg_val)){echo $d = array_sum($pkg_val);}?><br>
Total Amount: <?php if(isset($total_amt)){echo $e = array_sum($total_amt);}?>
          <br>
Grand Total:
<?php
$sum = array();
if (isSet($a))
    $sum[] = $a;
if (isSet($b))
    $sum[] = $b;
if (isSet($c))
    $sum[] = $c;
if (isSet($d))
    $sum[] = $d;
if (isSet($e))
    $sum[] = $e;
echo array_sum($sum);
?>
```

---

You need to use `&&` (AND) instead of `||` (OR).

```
if (isSet($a) && isSet($b) && ...) {
    //code
}
```

This can be simplified to

```
if  (isSet($a,b,$c,$d,$e)) {
    //code
}
```

---

You may ask why?

```
isset($a) || isset($b) || isset($c) || isset($d) || isset($e)
```

When you describe it in words it becomes clear:

> $a is set OR $b is set OR $c is set

Only one condition needs to be true for the whole expression to evaluate to true (and since some others are false, you will get the notice). Whereas when you use `&&` (AND), all expressions need to be true.

Comment: PHP is not case sensitive with functions and I like it this way better ;) because I promptly know what it means - not iss et, not i sset, but is set

Comment: @RishabhRaj Function names are not case-sensitive in PHP.

Comment: Don't think this is correct. $a would be the first variable and would be evaluated anyways. See MeNa's comment on OP.

Comment: @kingkero when I use
    if (isset($a) && isset($b) && ...) {
        //code
    }

Then it shows nothing.

Comment: @SubhajitSarkar thats because your if condition is failing and you have no else part

Answer (score 0):

works fine on my pc but try

```
 echo ($a = array_sum($box_chrs));
```

Comment: the problem is in
`<?php
          if(isset($a) || isset($b) || isset($c) || isset($d) || isset($e))
          {
            $sum = array($a, $b, $c, $d, $e);
            echo array_sum($sum);
          }
          ?>`